# how to use JNI in c++ android ndk

Tags: java, android, c++

I wish I could write in a file and read in with Android NDK but I can’t, I code in c++, I tried this but my game crash
it is called MainActivity.java and is in app/src/com/psdk/

```
package com.psdk;
 
import java.io.FileWriter;
import android.os.Bundle;
 
import android.Manifest.permission;
import android.content.Intent;
 
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
 
public class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity {
     
    private static final int ACCEPT_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTCODE = 8007;
     
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tata();
    }
     
    public String tata(){
        String string1 = "Hey you";
         
        if (requestPermissionsIfNeeded(this, ACCEPT_PERMISSIONS_REQUESTCODE)) {
            FileOutputStream fos ;
 
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt", true);
 
                FileWriter fWriter;
 
                try {
                    fWriter = new FileWriter(fos.getFD());
                    fWriter.write("hi");
                    fWriter.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    fos.getFD().sync();
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "tata";
    }
     
    public static boolean requestPermissionsIfNeeded(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
        return requestPermissionsNeeded(activity, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, requestCode);
    }
     
    private static boolean requestPermissionsNeeded(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        final List<String> notGrantedPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                notGrantedPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!notGrantedPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, notGrantedPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), requestCode);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I don’t know how to use it (I don’t even know if this script works   ')

In c++ I tried this: (the cpp is in app/src/cpp/)

```
ANativeActivity *activity = sf::getNativeActivity();
JNIEnv* env = activity->env;            
jclass cls_Env = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/psdk/NativeActivity");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_Env, "tata", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jobject obj_File = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, activity->clazz, mid, NULL);
```

here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.sfmldev.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission>
 
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/sfml_logo"
        android:hasCode="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true">
 
        <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/sfml_logo"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
 
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="sfml-activity" />
            <meta-data android:name="sfml.app.lib_name" android:value="sfml-example" />
 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But it doesn’t work, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have not linked the library in activity. Check out this tutorial
https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni#java

Update

Sorry for delay. See my Websocket native project on github for resolve your issue https://github.com/Ibernato93/NativeWebSocket/blob/main/app/src/main/cpp/ws_no_tls.hpp

Mark my answer correct if I've been of any help

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help, however I have another mistake:

```
ANativeActivity *activity = sf::getNativeActivity();
JNIEnv* env = activity->env;            
jclass cls_Env = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/psdk/NativeActivity");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_Env, "tata", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jobject obj_File = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, activity->clazz, mid, NULL);
```

this code does not work, I have this to compile:

```
error: member reference type 'JNIEnv' (aka '_JNIEnv') is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
jclass cls_Env = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/psdk/NativeActivity");

error: too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'name', have 2 arguments
jclass cls_Env = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/psdk/NativeActivity");

error: member reference type 'JNIEnv' (aka '_JNIEnv') is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_Env, "tata", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

how? Thanks again for your help